# Can beforeload cancel HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webkit, safari-extension

I've read over the [`beforeload` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW9) from Apple, but I'm still a bit uncertain about how `beforeload` cancels a load, from a network perspective. Apple's documentation says:

> Safari 5.0 and later (and other WebKit-based browsers) generates a "beforeload" event before loading each subresource belonging to a webpage.

There's nothing in the sparse documentation here that suggests to me that a `beforeload` block *must* prevent a HTTP fetch of the resource. What does the operation of "loading" a Web resource entail (e.g., is there a formal definition of `load`ing in some W3C spec)? In Webkit's current implementation, does canceling a load with `beforeload` stop the browser from sending a HTTP request, or does it merely stop the resource from being rendered and firing a `load` event?

I'm primarily instead in these question to assess `beforeload`'s usefulness to block tracking images. I know there are other ways to do this (e.g., Chrome's `webRequest` API), but I want to know if `beforeonload` is also suitable.

Comment: At very least it seems to be used by AdBlock exactly for preventing loading.

Comment: I don't have an Apple handy, but generally blocking the event default/propagation does stop the web request.  You can easily test this on your system by using a free packet sniffer like Wireshark.

Answer (score 2):

The `beforeload` strictly speaking doesn't prevent anything; it just offers the opportunity to `preventDefault()`.

Does your stack use `dispatchMessage()`? This is asynchronous and allows fetching resources to start before you can prevent.

Have you read 
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/SafariExtensionGuide.pdf#page=88? It offers a synchronous approach (pp. 91-92)

ps
I would have added this as a comment rather than an answer but I cannot yet add comments

Comment: Sorry, yes, I should have specified that I do indeed mean "`preventDefault` within `beforeload`" whenever I refer to `beforeload` blocking anything. I'll look at your link now.